# What is using my Azure Blob Accounts

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

After starting to use it for a while we have accumulated a bunch of storage accounts.  There doesn’t seem to be a way to figure out if those storage accounts are used, and what they are used by.  It looks like even spinning up a VM creates a storage account.

Is there a way (without the PowerShell) to see what is being used and delete the unused storage?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We're not general server/hosting tech support.

Comment: You can view all of your storage accounts via the portal, and see what's in there. But honestly, there's no way for anyone to help, with the information you've given. It would just be wild guesses. And spinning up a vm doesn't equate to creating a storage account (there's a storage account setting, which *defaults* to a new storage account, since you must have one to store your vhd), and if you've never changed it, then possibly you've been creating new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, it's not possible to accurately give you an answer, but you can iterate over the storage accounts, and within that loop iterate the containers to see which ones have blobs or not. I would approach this from within VS by creating a new project, then using NuGet to add a reference to the WindowsAzure.Storage client library. This will make iterating those collections easier. It is essentially a wrapper to the Azure Management API. There is likely a way to do it with PS as well.